# how to stop activity indicator in imagecropper plugin, if user closes displayAlert?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

****issue is that** in step#2**, if user doesnt pick a options or simply closes displayAlert than `activityIndicator` runs for ever. Any idea how can I stop `Activity Indicator` if user closed displayAlert (In Step#2)?

ref: [imagecropper plugin](https://github.com/stormlion227/ImageCropper.Forms)

**Below is the full flow of code that you see:**

1. On MainPage - Start loading using `activityIndicator`
2. Open displayAlert, with 2 options: "upload image" or "take photo"
3. Open camera
4. Take Photo
5. Conform photo
6. go to main page and wait 2 seconds (this sucks but ok)
7. open crop image editor
8. Close crop image editor and go to main page
9. Stop loading using `activityIndicator`

defualt code from link

```
      //run loading if user picked a option
      activityIndicator.IsRunning = true;

     //this code always get run last thing in method
        new ImageCropper()
        {
          Success = (imageFile) =>
          {
             Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
             {
               //turn off loading
               activityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
               imageView.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(imageFile);
              });
           }
         }.Show(this);
```

Comment: have you tried to move the `activityIndicator.IsRunning = false;` to below: `}.Show(this);` ?

Comment: yeah i did tried that but than activity doesnt show up at all. what i can tell is that, `new ImageCropper()` always get last thing in a method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for late responses, actually I want to put this in comment, but it's really hard to read in comment.
I guess you can try this code:

```
    new ImageCropper()
    {
      Success = (imageFile) =>
      {
         Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
         {
           //turn off loading
           activityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
           imageView.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(imageFile);
          });
       },
       //this 'faiure' is not typo, check ImageCropper.cs in your link
       Faiure = () =>
            {
                activityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
            }
     }.Show(this);
```

Comment: you just saved me so much headache. thanks your solution does works!!